# Adding query parameter for every flask GET request

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Trying to figure out the right mechanism to use here.

I want to modify the flask request coming in every time.

I think the request is immutable, so I am trying to figure out if this mechanism exists.

Basically, I want to append a string onto the end of the request coming in.

I can hook into the request and the right time in a before_request handler like this:

```
@app.before_app_request
def before_request_custom():
    # Get the request
    req = flask.request

    method = str(req.method)

    if method == "GET":
        # Do stuff here
        pass
```

But I am not sure what to actually do to add this in, and don't see a way to accomplish it...I guess i could redirect, but that seems silly in this case. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do this, but one alternative approach could be to create a separate view in the database with the 'deleted = False' condition, and reconfigure the library to use the view instead of the table.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Pending something more elegant within the flask framework, may have to got wiht this. Or, do something with redirection...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The request object is immutable (https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/wrappers/#base-wrappers), but `request.args` or `request.form` can be set from `ImmutableOrderedMultiDict` to just `OrderedMultiDict` using Subclassing on Flask (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/subclassing/). Here's an example of how you could add that `filter[is_deleted]=False` URL param:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Request
from werkzeug.datastructures import OrderedMultiDict

class MyRequest(Request):
    parameter_storage_class = OrderedMultiDict

class MyApp(Flask):
    def __init__(self, import_name):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(import_name)
        self.before_request(self.my_before_method)

    def my_before_method(self):
        if "endpoint" in request.base_url:
            request.args["filter[is_deleted]"] = "False"

app = MyApp(__name__)
app.request_class = MyRequest

@app.route('/endpoint/')
def endpoint():
    filter = request.args.get('filter[is_deleted]')
    return filter
```

This way you can modify `request.args` before you actually send the request.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
from flask import g

@app.before_request
def before_request():

    # Get the request
    req = flask.request

    method = str(req.method)

    if method == "GET":
        g.my_addon = "secret sauce"
    return None
```

Then, `g.my_addon` is available in every view function:

```
from flask import g

@app.route('/my_view')
def my_view():
    if g.my_addon == "secret sauce":
         print('it worked!')
```

Comment: Not quite what I need, I have a library that automatically exposes endpoints to my DB based on some configuration. I basically want the server to think it got requested /endpoint/?filter[is_deleted]=False when it really got requested /endpoint/. So I think, using G, I would have to then still add in the filter on an endpoint by endpoint basis. Does that make sense?

Comment: Can't you just do: `g.my_addon = "filter[is_deleted]=False"`, then handle that in the view function?

Comment: Not really. My endpoints are auto generated - I could override things in the library that I am using, but there is no explicit function like my view that calls out the route, it is generated at start time of the server. I was trying to achieve this by rewriting the inbound URL so I did not have to do anything in my library.

Answer (score 0):

Using [test_request_context()](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.test_request_context) you can make the trick.

Related: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#accessing-request-data